# 20.04 can't recognized and opened any files on router USB flash disk

Tags: usb, flash, 20.04, disk, router

I used wireless router(ASUS RT-AC1200GU) with USB socket at home. In files manager, USB flash disk as a files sharer. They work fine with Ubuntu 18.04 and Windows10.

After I installed Ubuntu 20.04 LTS, I can't open the USB flash disk! someone say: you need add `"client min protocol = CORE"` into `/etc/samba/smb.conf` follow `"[global]"`. I done,so I can open USB flash disk,but all icons of subdirectories and files are same! the .doc .xls .ppt .pdf.....all files can't recognized and opened :-(

How can I do? save me!!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks M.A.K. Ripon's help for my poor English.

Now I know above problem is a bug(samba-bug1872476).

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/samba/+bug/1872476
https://launchpad.net/~sergiodj/+archive/ubuntu/samba-bug1872476-v2

The answer is:

add `client min protocol = NT1` into `/etc/samba/smb.conf` following `[global]`

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:sergiodj/samba-bug1872476-v2
sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade
```